# SQL Server trigger to add future records to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I would have to say I am very new to SQL Server triggers but I hope some good samaritan will help me with this problem. I want to set a trigger that checks if a record has been added to a table and if so insert a series of records into a different table adding time to the timestamp in the monitored table. I have wrote what I how is easy to understand pseudo-code that will help in the creation of these triggers.

IF there is a new record in the `tBatch` table with a specific batch ID, then insert a record into `DeSchedule`.

Query to find new records in `tBatch` and pull data from `tBatch`:

```
SELECT  
    b.BatchID, b.fermNumber, b.BatchStartTime, b.PropStartTime, b.SiteID
FROM 
    [DDIApplication].[dbo].[tBatch] b
INNER JOIN 
    [DDIApplication].[dbo].[tBatchDetails] bd ON b.id = bd.BatchDetailID
```

Trigger

IF there is a new record in `tBatch`, create these records in `DeSchedule`

`DeSchedule` schema

```
| ID | SiteID | Timestamp | BatchID | FermNumber | SampleAge | Ethanol | Glucose | SampleCompleted |
```

Create these records in `DeSchedule`:

```
insert into DeSchedule(DATEADD(hour, 6, PropStartTime), 6666, 1, YP6, , , )

insert into DeSchedule(DATEADD(hour, 10, PropStartTime), 6666, 1, YPD, , , )

insert into DeSchedule(DATEADD(hour, 10, BatchStartTime), 6666, 1, 10, , , )

insert into DeSchedule(DATEADD(hour, 20, BatchStartTime), 6666, 1, 20, , , )

insert into DeSchedule(DATEADD(hour, 30, BatchStartTime), 6666, 1, 30, , , )

insert into DeSchedule(DATEADD(hour, 40, BatchStartTime), 6666, 1, 40, , , )

insert into DeSchedule(DATEADD(hour, 50, BatchStartTime), 6666, 1, 50, , , ) 

insert into DeSchedule(DATEADD(hour, 65, BatchStartTime), 6666, 1, DROP, , , )

insert into DeSchedule(DATEADD(hour, 70, BatchStartTime), 6666, 1, BW, , , )
```

Additional trigger

When records are entered into `tBatchDetails`, check against `DeSchedule` to try and match (BatchID, SampleAge, SiteID)

If record is found update record and insert (Ethanol, Glucose and check the SampleCompleted Bit) from the `tBatchDetails` Table

Query for `BatchDetailID`:

```
SELECT 
   [BatchDetailID], [ID],
   [SampleTimeStamp],
   [SampleAge], [Glucose], [Ethanol]
```

FROM 
       [DDIApplication].[dbo].[tBatchDetails]

`tBatchDetails` schema

```
| ID | TimeStamp | BatchTableID | SampleAge | BatchID | Ethanol | Glucose |
```

**Edited**

Instead of writing out all the inserts in the trigger is there a way to loop through the SampleAge Table and Insert a record for each SampleAge.

SampleAge Table schema

```
| SiteID | SampleAge | ScheduleTime |
|   1    |    YP6    |      6       |
```

So instead of:

```
insert into DeSchedule ([SiteID],[PreTimeStamp],[BatchID],[FermNumber],[SampleAge],[Ethanol],[Glucose],[SampleCompleted]) 
select SiteID, DATEADD(hour, 4, PropStartTime), BatchID, FirmNum, '4Hrs', NULL , NULL ,NULL  
from INSERTED
```

It would get the amount of hours for the dateadd function from ScheduleTime and the SampleAge from the SampleAge column of the SampleAge table. Then it 
will loop through the sample age table and insert a record for each sampleage that has the same SiteID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the trigger for tBatch table (adapt the insert into code to insert exactly what you need):

```
USE [test] --Change by your database Name
GO

CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_Insert_into_DeSchedule ON [dbo].[tBatch] 
AFTER INSERT 
AS 

BEGIN
insert into DeSchedule ([SiteID],[Timestamp],[BatchID],[FermNumber],[SampleAge],[Ethanol],[Glucose],[SampleCompleted]) 
select SiteID, DATEADD(hour, 6, PropStartTime), BatchID, 6666, 1, 'YP6', NULL , NULL  from INSERTED

insert into DeSchedule ([SiteID],[Timestamp],[BatchID],[FermNumber],[SampleAge],[Ethanol],[Glucose],[SampleCompleted]) 
select SiteID, DATEADD(hour, 10, PropStartTime), BatchID, 6666, 1, 'YPD', NULL , NULL  from INSERTED

insert into DeSchedule ([SiteID],[Timestamp],[BatchID],[FermNumber],[SampleAge],[Ethanol],[Glucose],[SampleCompleted]) 
select SiteID, DATEADD(hour, 10, PropStartTime), BatchID, 6666, 1, '10', NULL , NULL  from INSERTED

insert into DeSchedule ([SiteID],[Timestamp],[BatchID],[FermNumber],[SampleAge],[Ethanol],[Glucose],[SampleCompleted]) 
select SiteID, DATEADD(hour, 10, PropStartTime), BatchID, 6666, 1, '20', NULL , NULL  from INSERTED

insert into DeSchedule ([SiteID],[Timestamp],[BatchID],[FermNumber],[SampleAge],[Ethanol],[Glucose],[SampleCompleted]) 
select SiteID, DATEADD(hour, 10, PropStartTime), BatchID, 6666, 1, '30', NULL , NULL  from INSERTED

insert into DeSchedule ([SiteID],[Timestamp],[BatchID],[FermNumber],[SampleAge],[Ethanol],[Glucose],[SampleCompleted]) 
select SiteID, DATEADD(hour, 10, PropStartTime), BatchID, 6666, 1, '40', NULL , NULL  from INSERTED

insert into DeSchedule ([SiteID],[Timestamp],[BatchID],[FermNumber],[SampleAge],[Ethanol],[Glucose],[SampleCompleted]) 
select SiteID, DATEADD(hour, 10, PropStartTime), BatchID, 6666, 1, '50', NULL , NULL  from INSERTED

insert into DeSchedule ([SiteID],[Timestamp],[BatchID],[FermNumber],[SampleAge],[Ethanol],[Glucose],[SampleCompleted]) 
select SiteID, DATEADD(hour, 10, PropStartTime), BatchID, 6666, 1, 'DROP', NULL , NULL  from INSERTED

insert into DeSchedule ([SiteID],[Timestamp],[BatchID],[FermNumber],[SampleAge],[Ethanol],[Glucose],[SampleCompleted]) 
select SiteID, DATEADD(hour, 10, PropStartTime), BatchID, 6666, 1, 'BW', NULL , NULL  from INSERTED

END

GO
```

And the trigger for tBatchDetails table :

```
USE [test] --Change by your database Name
GO

CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_update_details_DeSchedule ON [dbo].[tBatchDetails]
    AFTER INSERT 
AS 


BEGIN
    DECLARE @BatchId int, @Ethanol varchar(10), @Glucose varchar(10), @SampleAge varchar(10);
    SELECT @BatchId = [BatchTablelID],@Ethanol = [Ethanol], @Glucose= [Glucose], @SampleAge = [SampleAge]  from INSERTED

    update [dbo].[DeSchedule] SET [Ethanol] = @Ethanol, [Glucose] = @Glucose WHERE [BatchID] = @BatchId AND [SampleAge] = @SampleAge

END

GO
```

Comment: This was perfect thank you very much. I have one other question to simplify this trigger. I will add to main post. @liotims